# What is good protection for outside timelapse? (During rain/thunderstorm)

Tags: equipment-recommendation, timelapse, weather

I've wanted to do some more timelapse shooting with my 60D, and be able to leave it running all day. My biggest issue here is now the weather with pop-up thunderstorms and heavy rains possible. Is there a decent protection setup for the camera+a lens to leave on a tripod for hours in those types of conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Attach it to a tall steel pole with a pointed top in the middle of your yard. It should be nicely sealed up after the lightning strike.

But seriously, you will need to start with a rather heavy tripod. Heavy rains usually have heavy winds, and no amount of rain protection will keep it dry if it's submerged in a puddle.

The pro section of your camera supplier should have a selection of waterproof housings. Assuming you don't want to spend the cost of the camera again on an experiment, get yourself a protect (clear) filter, a step ring, and some medium-weight plastic.

Wrap the plastic around the camera AND over the lens (with protect filter on).
Thread the step ring onto the lens through the plastic, and then slice it out from the opening. Your camera is now water-resistant to most things less than a hurricane or a pressure washer.